# How do I set a return URL during login on Codeigniter / Tank_Auth?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, tankauth, returnurl

The issue here is that when my user logs into my app, they always are redirected to the default controller.

I would like the user to be redirected to the page they were on before logging in.

So for example, if the user is reading forum post #12 (reading does not require login) and then decides to post an answer (answering requires login), once they login they should go back to post #12.

I am using PHP/Codeigniter 2.0.2 and the Tank_Auth library, and have in several of my controllers

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('/auth/login/');
    } else {

        //load stuff 
     }
```

***My question is***

What is the best way to set a return URL (Cookie? GET?), and how would that be implemented?

If you're familiar with Tank_Auth, in which files should I make these changes?

Any roadmaps are welcome, even if you don't use Tank_Auth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the solution I've been using with tank_auth, it's probably not the best, but I've found it works well for me.

*In the controller*

```
if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()){
   $encoded_uri = preg_replace('"/"', '_', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   redirect('/login/'.$encoded_uri);        
}elseif($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in(FALSE)){  // logged in, not activated
   redirect('/user/reactivate/');
}else{
   //Logged IN Stuff Here
}
```

*Modified Tank Auth Login Function (controllers/auth.php)*

```
function login($return_to = "")
{
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        if ($this->tank_auth->login(
            $this->form_validation->set_value('login'),
            $this->form_validation->set_value('password'),
            $this->form_validation->set_value('remember'),
            $data['login_by_username'],
            $data['login_by_email'])) {
           //...Other Stuff Here
           $decoded_uri = preg_replace('"_"','/',$return_to);
           redirect($decoded_uri);
        }
    }
}
```

**You may need to change the preg_replace to something else if your urls have _ in them, I just used that because it works for me**

EDIT

I've updated the function, this is one from another project that we heavily modified the tank auth stuff, so if stuff is a bit different, I'm sorry

As for the passing the encode_uri stuff, I've added the following to the routes.php file (config/routes.php)

```
$route['auth/login/(:any)'] = 'auth/login/$1';
$route['auth/login'] = 'auth/login'; //Probably don't need this one now
```

Comment: this is an interesting solution -- I see you place the `$encoded_uri` as a segment after `/login/` -- then your Tank_auth function has an arg called `$return_to` -- how are you passing the `$encoded_uri` to the Tank_Auth function?

Answer (score 8):

I Recently implemented this solution on a webpage I was working.

In the **controller/auth** file add a reference to the **user_agent library**:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('security');
    $this->load->library('tank_auth');
    $this->lang->load('tank_auth');
    $this->load->library('user_agent'); //This is the line you are adding
}
```

In the **views/auth/login_form.php** and taking advantage of the **CodeIgniter's user_agent library** add a **hidden input tag** which will contain the **referrer url** as follows:

```
<?=form_hidden('redirect_url', $this->agent->referrer());?>
<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Let me in'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

After that, all you have to do is redirect the users to the content of the input named **"redirect_url"** when the **user posts** the **login data** to the **login action**:

```
/**
 * Login user on the site
 *
 * @return void
*/
function login()
{
    /*.... Beginning of the login action function...  
      ....
      ....
    */

    if ($this->tank_auth->login(
                $this->form_validation->set_value('login'),
                $this->form_validation->set_value('password'),
                $this->form_validation->set_value('remember'),
                $data['login_by_username'],$data['login_by_email'])) //valid
    {
        redirect( $this->input->post('redirect_url'));
    }
}
```

This works great for me... It's fine and simple. I believe it can help you.

Let me know about anything.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I solved it as follows

*In your controller*

Add this:    `$this->load->library(array('tank_auth');`

```
if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
  $encoded_uri = preg_replace('"/"', '_', $this->uri->uri_string());
  redirect('/auth/login/'.$encoded_uri);
} else { 
 // Logged IN Stuff Here    
}
```

*In Tank Auth Controller (controllers/auth.php)*

```
function login($return_to = "")
{
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
    if ($this->tank_auth->login(
        $this->form_validation->set_value('login'),
        $this->form_validation->set_value('password'),
        $this->form_validation->set_value('remember'),
        $data['login_by_username'],
        $data['login_by_email'])) {
         // success
         $decoded_uri = preg_replace('"_"','/',$return_to);
         redirect($decoded_uri);
    }
}
}
```

*I replaced `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` with this `$this->uri->uri_string()` because that allow you get /controller/method/...etc. to redirect later in tank auth controller*

**That work perfect for me and how said @Cubed Eye "You may need to change the preg_replace to something else if your urls have _ in them"**

Thanks to @Cubed Eye

I hope this helps someone else too.